# How do I set the character limit for .load

Tags: jquery

I'm pulling in a body of text from another page, but want to limit the amount of characters the .load event pulls. How do I control the amount of characters that are pulled from the class ".paragraph"?

Here is what I have so far:

```
$("document").ready(function(){   
    // Blog Descriptions
    $( ".blog-description-3" ).load( "/blog.html .blog-post:nth-of-type(3) .blog-content .paragraph");
});
```

Comment: You need to use the `$.ajax` or `$.get` method for this. `.load` can't do what you want.

Comment: You can't limit the number of characters the method pulls in. But you can manipulate the returned string and cut it to your needs with `substr(0, n)`

Comment: @ZoltanToth I saw this method, but wasn't sure how to apply it to the code above.

Comment: as @undefined mentioned, first you have to use `$.ajax` to pull the data and store them in a variable let say name `var myData`. then manipulate the variable content as you need and then use something like this: `$( ".blog-description-3" ).html(myData);` to inset what is inside the variable to your html element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't limit the number of characters the method pulls in. But you can manipulate the returned string and cut it to your needs with `substr()`

```
$(".blog-description-3").load("/blog.html .blog-post:nth-of-type(3) .blog-content .paragraph", function() {
    var txt = $(".blog-description-3").text().substr(0, 20);
    $(".blog-description-3").text(txt);
});
```

Comment: This worked beautifully and I thank you very much for your time and knowledge!